# Given a set of points S, and a point p determine whether there exist a half-plane L such that L contains p but does not contain any other point from S

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given a set of points S, and a point p, determine whether there exist a half-plane L such that L contains p, but does not contain any other point from S.

My solution:

find the CH(S) - o(nlogn).

check if p is inside CH(S) - o(n).

return true iff p is inside CH(S).

Total time complexity - o(nlogn).

Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: The construction of the convex hull is known to be possible in time O(N Log H).

Comment: There is indeed a direction connection to the convex hull: the answer is positive iff p is outside the hull.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In the worst case CH(S) = S. I think OP wants a o(n) solution.

Comment: @firev2: the OP was not explicit about the "desired" complexity. (And o(n) is not possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your proposed algorithm that we're considering a Euclidean space with three dimensions (or even a fixed number of dimensions), yes, there's a linear-time algorithm by formulating the problem as a linear program and solving it with Megiddo's algorithm.